# JS and CSS not loading on Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I have set my environment to Development.

```
export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

My _Layout.cshtml is default with the below

```
    <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>

 /// more layout.cshtml


   <environment names="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
```

It's strange though no lib folder is created when I execute dotnet run, and so no js or css gets loaded.  I am not sure how you get this code loaded in a dev environment and I can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Please don't force tags into the question title http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: What do you mean by "no lib folde it's created?" Do you expect a lib folder created? A grunt or gulp task can do that but it's not magical, if your scripts files aren't in lib folder they aren't going to be served

Comment: @addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"   ?